# imageView is bigger then parrent

Tags: android, android-layout

I would need some help with design a layout. I'm trying to design something like this:
[image]

My problem is that on some devices (with very small width) the imageViews are to big and are not visible. My aim is to make design with two equals columns and imageViews into. A imageView can be max so width as column (without padding). Probably should be scaled to max allow size. I've tried with GridLayout and TableLayout connected with scaleType but the imagesViews are always bigger then column.

Do have someone an idea how can I achieve similar effect?

Best regards,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution :)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/awards_status"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/awards_status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".5">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/awards_one_dwarf" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/awards_status"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".5">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/awards_one_dwarf" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking into imageView.AdjustViewBounds(true);

Comment: yes, I have and imageViews are still bigger then column

Comment: are the images really huge? if not you wrap_content,  how about using a LinearLayout (orientation horizontal), then add linear layout(columns) orientation vertical inside, and then add imageViews inside that.  Does this make sense?
you could set the inner linearLayouts as layout_width  =1 for both